# Microsoft Word continually crashes when opening document containing custom template

Tags: windbg

I am running Word (32-bit version) on a 64-bit version of Windows 7. The application always crashes when trying to open a file containing a template. This template works fine on several other machines running the same basic configuration. Below are the contents of the WINWORD.dump file:

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\WINWORD.EXE_140815_132608.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: '
*** procdump.exe  -e -w -ma winword.exe
*** Unhandled exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION'
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;srv*c:\MicrosoftSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Fri Aug 15 13:26:08.000 2014 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 4 days 10:02:34.392
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:01.000
................................................................
..................................................
Loading unloaded module list
...........
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(24ec.1fd0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for WWLIB.DLL - 
eax=00000001 ebx=00000073 ecx=061412b0 edx=1079701c esi=007ec9d3 edi=00000000
eip=0f7d3425 esp=00406bf4 ebp=00406f08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x9e76c:
0f7d3425 ff90b4000000    call    dword ptr [eax+0B4h] ds:002b:000000b5=????????
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for MSO.DLL - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for WINWORD.EXE - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for nvwgf2um.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+9e76c
0f7d3425 ff90b4000000    call    dword ptr [eax+0B4h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0f7d3425 (WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x0009e76c)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 000000b5
Attempt to read from address 000000b5

PROCESS_NAME:  WINWORD.EXE

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000b5

READ_ADDRESS:  000000b5 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+9e76c
0f7d3425 ff90b4000000    call    dword ptr [eax+0B4h]

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  winword.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001fd0

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_CALL

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0f7cffa7 to 0f7d3425

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00406f08 0f7cffa7 007ec9d3 1079701c 004071d4 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x9e76c
00407254 0f7f1408 004072d0 1079701c 00000001 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x9b2ee
00407288 0f7cef64 004072d0 0000000b 00000000 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xbc74f
004072e8 0f81ea89 09758728 00407330 0040c638 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x9a2ab
004079e8 0f81e8fc 09758728 00000000 0040be90 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe9dd0
00407aec 0f81de29 00408504 0040be90 0040c638 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe9c43
0040958c 0f81cfe0 0b464d18 004095fc 0040960c WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe9170
0040d0e8 0f81ca65 0b464d18 0040d164 00000033 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe8327
0040d37c 0f81c941 04011009 0040d3dc 0040d3d0 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe7dac
0040d3a8 0f81c86c 0040d3e4 0f81c992 ffffffff WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe7c88
0040d3e8 6ad0ba64 0040d458 00000001 04d7a818 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0xe7bb3
0040d400 6ad0b95f 0040d458 37d8b710 09657260 MSO!Ordinal806+0x30
0040d4a0 6ac371e5 00000000 00000094 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal502+0x1f1
0040d4c4 6ac048be 00000000 04d7a818 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal3258+0x122a
0040d4ec 6ac0467a 00000000 00000094 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal3269+0x1ec
0040d510 6ac0863c 00000000 00000094 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal2370+0x12e
0040d530 6ace1a26 00000000 00000094 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal4047+0x6aa
0040d564 6ad0b87a 00000000 00000002 096b9b44 MSO!Ordinal1819+0x3c1
0040d59c 6ad0b7fb 099f57b8 00000001 0614b560 MSO!Ordinal502+0x10c
0040d5b0 6ad0b75e 00000000 096b9b40 00000002 MSO!Ordinal502+0x8d
0040d5e0 6ad0b568 009e0550 6af427d4 00000001 MSO!Ordinal8445+0x55
0040d5f8 6abb98f0 099f57b8 099e0550 0040d634 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4df
0040d624 6ad0b548 6ad0b54f 0040d634 6af427d4 MSO!Ordinal6791+0x133
0040d63c 6ad0b6f1 6af427d4 00000001 0040d6b4 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4bf
0040d660 6ad0b568 009d7c48 6aeb73ac 00000001 MSO!Ordinal9073+0x8c
0040d678 6abb98f0 099f5b78 099d7c48 0040d6b4 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4df
0040d6a4 6ad0b548 6ad0b54f 0040d6b4 6aeb73ac MSO!Ordinal6791+0x133
0040d6bc 6ad0b5e8 6aeb73ac 00000001 00000001 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4bf
0040d6d8 6ad0b568 09a1ef10 6aeaeec4 00000001 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x55f
0040d6f0 6abb98f0 09a054d0 09a1ef10 0040d72c MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4df
0040d71c 6ad0b548 6ad0b54f 0040d72c 6aeaeec4 MSO!Ordinal6791+0x133
0040d734 6ad0b3db 6aeaeec4 00000001 09a1ef10 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x4bf
0040d75c 6ac8f807 0040d790 6aeaeec4 0040d8c0 MSO!Ordinal4173+0x352
0040d7d8 6abba3c8 096ed6e0 00000000 096ed6a8 MSO!Ordinal6262+0xc50
0040d85c 6aba6040 096ed6a8 09a1ef10 0040d8c0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x7bf
0040d8ac 6abba395 096ed6a8 0040d8c0 00000002 MSO!Ordinal8497+0x1f6
0040d8d0 6abba368 096ed6a8 096ed6a8 096ed738 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x78c
0040d8f4 6abba30e 00000001 096ed700 096e29f8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x75f
0040d918 6abba30e 00000001 096e29c0 096e1a28 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d93c 6abba30e 00000001 096e19f0 096e1a80 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d960 6abba30e 00000001 096e1a48 096e1ad8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d984 6abba30e 00000001 096e1aa0 096e1b30 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d9a8 6abba30e 00000001 096e1af8 096e1be0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d9cc 6abba30e 00000001 096e1ba8 096e1c38 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040d9f0 6abba30e 00000001 096e1c00 096e1c90 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040da14 6abba30e 00000001 096e1c58 096e1ce8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040da38 6abba30e 00000001 096e1cb0 096e1d40 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040da5c 6abba30e 00000001 096e1d08 096e1d98 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040da80 6abba30e 00000001 096e1d60 096e1df0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040daa4 6abba30e 00000001 096e1db8 096e1ea0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dac8 6abba30e 00000001 096e1e68 096d10f0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040daec 6abba30e 00000001 096d10b8 096e1768 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040db10 6abba30e 00000001 096e1730 096e17c0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040db34 6abba30e 00000001 096e1788 096e1818 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040db58 6abba30e 00000001 096e17e0 096b68b8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040db7c 6abba30e 00000001 096b6880 061c97b8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dba0 6abba30e 00000001 061c9780 061c6038 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dbc4 6abba30e 00000001 061c6000 061c6090 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dbe8 6abba30e 00000001 061c6058 061c6140 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dc0c 6abba30e 00000001 061c6108 061e70e8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dc30 6abba30e 00000001 061e70b0 061e7198 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dc54 6abba30e 00000001 061e7160 061297f0 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dc78 6abba30e 00000001 06140ce8 00000001 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dc9c 6abba243 00000001 061114f8 00000000 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x705
0040dcc0 6ac6a8d1 061297b8 061519b8 0619eee8 MSO!Ordinal1912+0x63a
0040dcf0 6abedb3f 00040a82 061519b8 107972b8 MSO!Ordinal1003+0x1b3
0040dd08 6abedaaf 00000001 00000001 00000000 MSO!Ordinal7113+0x21b
0040dd24 6abed920 00040a82 00000001 00000000 MSO!Ordinal7113+0x18b
0040dd38 0f799a06 00040a82 00000001 0f7985c0 MSO!Ordinal287+0x10
0040dd5c 0f798409 107972b8 00000000 6aa9761f WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x64d4d
0040dd84 0f796325 b958c8d5 752c1222 0f730000 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x63750
0040fdfc 013515c4 01350000 00000000 00734767 WWLIB!DllGetClassObject+0x6166c
0040fe20 01351558 01350000 00000000 00734767 WINWORD+0x15c4
0040feb4 752c338a 7efde000 0040ff00 77169f72 WINWORD+0x1558
0040fec0 77169f72 7efde000 61a2d403 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0040ff00 77169f45 013510d4 7efde000 ffffffff ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0040ff18 00000000 013510d4 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  wwlib!DllGetClassObject+9e76c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: WWLIB

IMAGE_NAME:  WWLIB.DLL

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5396ad52

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_CALL_c0000005_WWLIB.DLL!DllGetClassObject

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_CALL_wwlib!DllGetClassObject+9e76c

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/WINWORD_EXE/15_0_4631_1000/5396ad5c/WWLIB_DLL/15_0_4631_1000/5396ad52/c0000005/000a3425.htm?Retriage=1

WATSON_IBUCKET:  362486679

WATSON_IBUCKETTABLE:  17

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: You need a 32-bit dump and open the dump using x86 version of WinDbg to be able to see a meaningful call stack. The debugger output you have pasted in your question is useless as it is.

Comment: I used procdump to generate the attached dump which should be in 32bit format along with WinDbg x86.

Answer (score 1):

Office symbols are not available publicly and it don't think we can have a conclusive find using a dump in this case. If you are using procdump use the -ma switch to generate a full dump and engage MS Support for a better analysis of the problem. If this is with a specific template which already works on other installations possibly you would like to understand the differences between a working and a non-working installation.

The crash depicted is because of a invalid address access however how is template responsible for such an address is not something which can be found from the dump without private symbols of word.